# Import a variable from .mat and export to CSV

Tags: matlab, char, export-to-csv, cell-array, matlab-struct

I have a `.mat` file which contains a struct (called `wiki`),

[image]

in which there is a field called `full_path` containing data as follows:

```
ans = 
Columns 1 through 4

{'17/10000217_198…'}    {'48/10000548_192…'}    {'12/100012_1948-…'}    {'65/10001965_193…'}

Columns 5 through 8

{'16/10002116_197…'}    {'02/10002702_196…'}    {'41/10003541_193…'}    {'39/100039_1904-…'} 
and so on
```

How can I create a `.csv` file with the data present in the curly braces?

Comment: Just to make sure I understand: you want the columns of val to be written to a csv file as a single line, i.e. `17/10000217_198…,48/10000548_192…` etc. ? Also, what did you try?

Comment: Previously I tried the same function, but I passed the text file instead. How can I pass this val ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is quite a common problem, which requires very basic functions:

```
wiki = struct2array(load('wiki.mat', 'wiki'));
fid = fopen('q52688399.csv', 'w');
fprintf(fid,'%s\n', wiki.full_path{:});
fclose(fid);
```

The above will produce a ~2MB text tile containing a single column of strings.

Comment: As `{'16/10002116_197…'}` is a file name every character of it is occupying individual cell. How can I keep a filename limited in a single cell only?

Comment: Did you try the code? The way I created `val` in my example is just a demonstration that shows that each cell is converted to a different "entry" in the resulting `.csv`. If your cells contain long strings - you'll get long strings. If your cells contain a single character each - you'll get a single character per entry.

Comment: Actually, I have wiki.mat file, inside which there are multiple fields as gender,full_path,location etc. Now the above shown `val` data is inside full_path. So how do I write script for this?

Comment: Start by loading the required field: `val = struct2array(load('wiki.mat','full_path'));` then `csvwrite('filename.csv', val);`... It should be as simple as that.

Comment: Please see the screenshot [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1dwMDS4_G1yAukWd9WPTPMWoxwo8i2nXI). Also link to .mat file is [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1tDsPBlDekAGb06QpAKPZm7iR8qlhrq2P). Please suggest required commands.

Comment: @Anurag Please see the updated answer. If it is sufficient, consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234) the answer.